# How can I tell which of my ports I compiled myself and which I installed from pre-compiled binary packages?

Tags: freebsd

I have two FreeBSD 10.2-RELEASE systems and I'm trying to set up the second to be almost identical to the first. I don't wish to use ZFS snapshots for this task; I would just like to select, install, and compile the same software versions.

During the installation of the first system I know that I installed some binary ports by using the `pkg` tool and I also compiled some packages from source with `make install clean` in the `/usr/ports/` hierarchy.

Now when I run `pkg info` on the first system it shows me both of these types. I'd like to know if there is any way that I could differentiate which were compiled from source, without looking back through my shell history.

I have found out that I can do `pkg query -e '%a = 0' %o` to find *non-automatically installed* packages, which must then be those that I have selected, but I still can't quite tell which I compiled from source.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play with repository (`%R`). First try:

```
pkg query "%R %o" | grep unknown
```

Of course you can filter with `awk` (`awk '/unknown/ {print $2}'`) or `sed`.